How to run integration tests in ansible over ssh
I'm trying to run simple hello world ansible integration test over ssh. How to authenticate ssh connection using username and password?
I've tried the following command
ansible-test integration --target "ssh:user@192.168.77.143,python=3.10"

but it didn't asked a password. Instead ansible generated tests/integration/inventory with the following content
[testgroup]
testhost ansible_connection="ssh" ansible_pipelining="yes" ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/python3.10" ansible_host="192.168.77.143" ansible_user="user" ansible_ssh_private_key_file="/home/yaroslav/.ansible/test/id_rsa" ansible_ssh_extra_args=""

Adding ansible_ssh_pass option to this file didn's help as ansible-test command overrides this inventory file.
What can I do to run integration tests on the specified machine?
